# 1-st WB open macro from 2-nd WB, which close 1-st WB and proceed macro 2-nd WB

Tags: vba, excel, events

could u pls tell exactly, how to put this command (application ontime) i have the issue. See below, I tried use Application.Run

```
Sub FirstMacro() '
    Workbooks.Open Range("a1")      
    Application.Run, "Second.xlsm!module1.SecondMacro" 
End Sub 


Sub SecondMacro() '
    Workbooks("first.XLSM").Close SaveChanges:=True '
    'at this place macro interrupted, but i need to proceed this..
    Windows("Second.xlsm").Activate 
    Range("e4:l100").Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    'and next actions...
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Can you please [edit] to clarify your question (and title) with a proper explanation of what you're trying to do, where the problem is, what you've tried, and what's going wrong?  Also check out "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]" .

Comment: This won't work that way. If workbook1 starts a macro in workbook2, the macro still runs under the scope of workbook1 (which started the macro). Workbook1 has the control over the the running macro. So if you now close the workbook1 this immediately stops that macro (and everything that was started by workbook1). You cannot prevent that.